# What is the Sanskrit root word for “ viññāṇa”?

Tags: sutras, translation

In dependent origination , the word “ viññāṇa” arises and it is translated as consciousness. I am not satisfied and I guess some other members of this site are also not satisfied because then the dependent origination becomes: given volitional formations, consciousness arises. Isn’t volitional formation and ignorance itself due to consciousness?

Therefore in order to understand “viññāṇa” I need to understand what is the Sanskrit root for the Pali word “ viññāṇa”?

I looked up online Sanskrit dictionary, there is a word “[vinn](https://www.learnsanskrit.cc/translate?search=vinna&dir=se)” which means “understanding “.
Do you think “vinn” is the root word for “ viññāṇa” ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Pali dictionary says [viññāṇa](https://suttacentral.net/define/vi%C3%B1%C3%B1%C4%81%E1%B9%87a?lang=en) is from vi + jñā; cp. Vedic vijñāna cognition. A Sanskrit dictionary provides many definitions & references for [vijñāna](https://sanskritdictionary.org/vijnana).

There is a contentious [common theory](https://www.learnreligions.com/vijnana-449563#:%7E:text=The%20Sanskrit%20word%20vijnana%20is,mind%22%20are%20citta%20and%20manas.) the Sanskrit word vijnana is formed from the root jna, which means "to know" and the prefix vi- indicates separation or division. However, this attempt to impute an unwholesome 'duality' upon 'vijnana' has no relevance in the Teachings of the Buddha because (in the Teachings of the Buddha) viññāṇa continues to arise for the Fully Enlightened, for example, as follows:

> And what is the ending of the world? Dependent on the eye & forms
> there arises eye-consciousness. The meeting of the three is contact.
> From contact as a requisite condition comes feeling. From feeling as a
> requisite condition comes craving. Now, from the remainderless
> cessation & fading away of that very craving comes the cessation of
> clinging. From the cessation of clinging comes
> the cessation of becoming. From the cessation of becoming comes the
> cessation of birth. From the cessation of birth, then aging & death,
> sorrow, lamentation, pain, distress, & despair all cease. Such is the
> cessation of this entire mass of stress & suffering. This is the
> ending of the world.
>
> [SN 12.44](https://www.accesstoinsight.org/tipitaka/sn/sn12/sn12.044.than.html)

The suttas are clear in many places viññāṇa cannot arise alone; that there can be no viññāṇa without an object or other aggregates.

> Good, bhikkhus. It is good that you understand the Dhamma taught by me thus. For in many ways I have stated consciousness to be dependently arisen, since without a condition there is no origination of consciousness.... Bhikkhus, consciousness is reckoned by the particular condition dependent upon which it arises. When consciousness arises dependent on the eye and forms, it is reckoned as eye-consciousness; when consciousness arises dependent on the ear and sounds, it is reckoned as ear-consciousness; when consciousness arises dependent on the nose and odours, it is reckoned as nose-consciousness; when consciousness arises dependent on the tongue and flavours, it is reckoned as tongue-consciousness; when consciousness arises dependent on the body and tangibles, it is reckoned as body-consciousness; when consciousness arises dependent on the mind and mind-objects, it is reckoned as mind-consciousness.
>
> [MN 38](https://suttacentral.net/mn38/en/bodhi?lang=en&reference=none&highlight=false)

> Were someone to say, 'I will describe a coming, a going, a passing away, an arising, a growth, an increase, or a proliferation of consciousness apart from form, from feeling, from perception, from fabrications,' that would be impossible.
>
> [SN 22.53](https://www.accesstoinsight.org/tipitaka/sn/sn22/sn22.053.than.html)

The teaching of Dependent Origination refers to the arising of an *ignorant consciousness* dependent upon ignorance & sankhara. That is all. Dependent origination is not about the arising of all consciousness, as previously demonstrated/quoted from  SN 12.44. For example, in respect to Dependent Origination sense contact, for which consciousness is one of three contributory factors, [SN 22.81](https://www.accesstoinsight.org/tipitaka/sn/sn22/sn22.081.than.html) says:

> To an uninstructed, run-of-the-mill person, touched by that which is
> felt born of **contact with ignorance**, craving arises.

Therefore, the consciousness referred to in Dependent Origination is *consciousness with ignorance*, i.e.,  an *ignorant consciousness*.

The word 'sankhara' in Dependent Origination ([SN 12.2](https://suttacentral.net/sn12.2/pli/ms?lang=en&layout=linebyline&reference=none&notes=asterisk&highlight=false&script=latin)) is plural & defined as kayasankharo (in & out breathing), vacisankharo (initial & sustained thought) & cittasankharo (perception & feeling), which Thanissaro has properly explained in
his PDF titled '[Shape of Suffering](https://www.accesstoinsight.org/lib/authors/thanissaro/shapeofsuffering.pdf)'. 'Sankhara', here, does not mean 'volitional formations'. 'Sankhara' meaning 'volitional formations' is found in suttas, such as [SN 22.56](https://suttacentral.net/sn22.56/en/bodhi?lang=en&reference=none&highlight=false) & [AN 3.23](https://suttacentral.net/an3.23/en/sujato?lang=en&layout=linebyline&reference=none&notes=asterisk&highlight=false&script=latin), which are not about Dependent Origination. The word 'volitional' or 'cetanā' is first found in Dependent Origination at the nama-rupa condition. The wrong view 'sankhara' in Dependent Origination refers to 'volitional formations' comes from the [Abhidhamma Paṭiccasamuppādavibhaṅga](https://suttacentral.net/vb6/en/anandajoti?lang=en&reference=none&highlight=false) and was perpetuated in the mass-market mainstream commentary called the Visuddhimagga. The contemporary translator Bhikkhu Bodhi, as shown in his many sutta footnotes, often interprets Sutta from the perspective of Abhidhamma because Abhidhamma is popular in Sri Lanka, where Bhikkhu Bodhi was trained. Another translator, the independent Australian monk named Sujato, abandoned his Thai roots and the explanations of Ajahn Chah and has reverted to the Abhidhamma & Visuddhimagga mass-market mainstream populist translation of 'choices', which is also wrong.

As previously explained, consciousness (viññāṇa) in the Teaching of the Buddha cannot arise without a sense object. Therefore, there can be no disembodied consciousness floating around in space searching for new parents & a new physical host to reincarnate into. What Dependent Origination explains is:

1. There is the underlying tendency of ignorance. ([AN 7.11](https://suttacentral.net/an7.11/en/sujato?lang=en&layout=linebyline&reference=none&notes=asterisk&highlight=false&script=latin)).
2. Ignorance stirs up sankhara (thoughts based on perceptions & feelings with agitated breathing)
3. Consciousness arises to know/become aware of these thoughts.
4. At nama-rupa, volition/intention arises to give inappropriate attention to the ignorant thoughts the mind has become consciousness of.

In summary, as explained above, formations (sankhara) and ignorance are not due to consciousness. It is the opposite. In the Teachings  Of The Buddha, consciousness arises due to ignorance & formations because consciousness cannot arise without a sense object.

Comment: Great answer. When consciousness doesn’t arise, where is it?

Comment: I suppose this question is similar to asking when a log fire goes out after the log is completely burned & consumed, where does  the fire go?

Comment: @DhammaDhatu vijāna is a separate word in Pali dictionary. It can not be vinnana.

Comment: you seem right here. there is no empty consciousness slot for volition - it depends on the persistence of consciousness

Answer (score 1):

> "Another important thing to notice about dependent co-arising is that it starts
> with ignorance. Ignorance is defined as not seeing things in terms of the four
> noble truths, because you’re basically seeing things in terms of your identity in a
> world. If you look in terms of the four noble truths, there’s no mention of
> identities or worlds at all, just what the suffering is, what’s causing it, and whether its cessation is possible. The Buddha’s approach is that you attack the cause and, because the cause is conditioned, it can change. It can cease. There’s also a path that attacks that cause and leads to the cessation."
>
> [Dependent Co-arising Right Now](https://www.dhammatalks.org/Archive/Writings/Transcripts/200818_Dependent_Co-arising_Right_Now.pdf) by Thanissaro Bhikkhu

Comment: Hi. The four noble truths mention the  words 'attachment', 'becoming' & 'jati', which  are aspects of identity. In his PDF called 'Shape Of Suffering', Thanissaro says jati means identity. Therefore, the 1st Noble Truth says 'birth/jati/identity' is suffering.